# Android - Double value always returns 00 after decimal

Tags: java, android, string, double, package-managers

I have a method to get any app's size. But the problem is **I always get .00 value after the decimal.**

Suppose, an app's size is 3.44

So, if I call my method then it will return a value of 3.00
And, it is same for every application. If any app's size is less than 1 mb, then I get 0.00. Please help me. Here is my method

```
    private String getAppsSize() {
        File cApp;
        DecimalFormat cDFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double appSizeInMegaBytes;
        String formattedText = null;
        try {
            cAInfo = cPManager.getApplicationInfo(getCurrentAppPackageName(), 0);
            cApp = new File(cAInfo.publicSourceDir);
            appSizeInMegaBytes = cApp.length() / 1048576;
            cDFormat.format(appSizeInMegaBytes);
            formattedText = Double.toString(appSizeInMegaBytes);
        }
 catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            showToast("Failed to count app size!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return formattedText;
    }
```

Here, I have a method getCurrentPackageName(). It causes no error. Because I am using it somewhere else. It works fine. So, now I don't know where my problem occurs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `cApp.length()` is returning a `long`, and then you are dividing that by another whole number, so you aren't going to get any decimal places that way. Try dividing by another double instead. So something like:

```
double megaByte = 1048576;
appSizeInMegaBytes = cApp.length() / megaByte;
```

Just adding a decimal to your divisor should also work: 
`appSizeInMegaBytes = cApp.length() / 1048576.0;`

Comment: Ok, it's working. But, I am getting a lot of value after decimal.  Now, if I call the method, so I am getting 3.0256983 (example). But, I want last two digits only after decimal

Answer (score 0):

I always rely on the good old implicit conversion of strings:

```
            formattedText = ""+appSizeInMegaBytes;
```

That's how you'll see if the value is good.

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing out your formatted text in these lines:

```
cDFormat.format(appSizeInMegaBytes);
formattedText = Double.toString(appSizeInMegaBytes);
```

The Format.format() call will return a string, so don't toss it out. Try this instead:

```
 formattedText = cDFormat.format(appSizeInMegaBytes);
```